# how do I get the IP of incoming ICMP due to UDP-send to dead client in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, networking, udp, icmp

so.. I'm doing a small multiplayer game with blocking UDP and IO.select. To my problem.. (In the server) reading from a UDP socket  (`packet, sender = @socket.recvfrom(1000)`) which have just sent a packet to a dead client results in a ICMP unreachable (and exception `Errno::ECONNRESET` in ruby). The problem is that I can't find any way whatsoever to extract the IP of that ICMP.. so I can clean out that dead client.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call [`recvmsg`](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/linux/man2html/man2/recvmsg.2.html) for the socket, and pass `MSG_ERRQUEUE` as the flag.

> The original destination address of the datagram that caused the error is supplied via msg_name.

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly how this works?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the source IP address of the ICMP packet will not always be the same address as your client.  Any router that handles packets for this connection could be the source, and the payload of the ICMP packet would contain the IP header + the first 8 bytes of the packet it relates to.